# UIManagedDocument and "This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores" Error

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, uimanageddocument

I'm trying to use a UIManagedDocument to set up my core data stack in an application i am building. I've got an object DocumentController that has this in the init method:

```
   - (id)init
{

if (self = [super init]) {
    //custom initialization

        NSString *path = [[DMDocumentController documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"logDatabase"];
        NSURL *documentURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

        self.managedDocument = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:documentURL];

        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

        self.managedDocument.persistentStoreOptions = options;

    }

    return self;
}
```

Then i've got this block method that called performWithDocument, which gives you access to the Document in the block. The Block is defined like this:

```
typedef void (^OnDocumentReady) (UIManagedDocument *document);
```

and the method looks like this:

```
- (void)performWithDocument:(OnDocumentReady)onDocumentReady
{
    void (^OnDocumentDidLoad)(BOOL) = ^(BOOL success) {
        onDocumentReady(self.managedDocument);
    };

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.managedDocument.fileURL path]]) {
        [self.managedDocument saveToURL:self.managedDocument.fileURL
                forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating
               completionHandler:OnDocumentDidLoad];
    } else if (self.managedDocument.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
        [self.managedDocument openWithCompletionHandler:OnDocumentDidLoad];
    } else if (self.managedDocument.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
        OnDocumentDidLoad(YES);
    }
}
```

Anyway, I anytime i try to insert a new Entity, my app crashes several seconds after the fact (when it tries to save) and I get the error message in the title. I'm not sure how to go about rectifying the issue when I thought the UIManagedDocument handled the core data stack stuff for me. Does any one have any pointers?